# A particular calculation of second partial derivative

Tags: partial-derivative

Let $z$ be a function of two variables $u$ and $v$ which are also functions of $x$ and $y$ such that $u=x^{2}y^{3}$ and $v=sin(\pi x)$ I have to compute $ \frac {\partial  ^ 2z}  { \partial  y \partial x } @ (x,y)=(-2,1)$ I am given $z(4,0)=10,$ $z_u(4,0)=5,$ $z_v(4,0)=7,$ $z_{uu}(4,0)=-2,$ $z_{uv}(4,0)=-1,$ $z_{vv}(4,0)=3$ Here is my attempt:

$\frac { \partial  z } { \partial  x } = \frac { \partial z } { \partial u } \frac { \partial  u } { \partial x } + \frac { \partial z } { \partial v } \frac { \partial v } { \partial x }$

Taking the partial derivative of both sides with respect to $y$

$\frac  \partial    { \partial  y }\frac { \partial  z } { \partial  x } =\frac  \partial    { \partial  y }( \frac { \partial z } { \partial u } \frac { \partial  u } { \partial x } + \frac { \partial z } { \partial v } \frac { \partial v } { \partial x })$

which produces

$\frac { \mathrm d ^ 2 z} { \partial y \partial x } = \frac { \partial ^ 2 z } { \partial y \partial u }  \frac { \partial u } { \partial x }  + \frac { \partial ^ 2 u } { \partial y \partial x }  \frac { \partial z } { \partial u } + \frac { \partial ^ 2 z } { \partial y \partial v }  \frac { \partial v } { \partial x }+\frac { \partial ^ 2 v } { \partial y \partial x }  \frac { \partial z } { \partial v }$

Now, $\frac { \partial u } { \partial x }, \frac { \partial ^ 2 u } { \partial y \partial x }, \frac { \partial z } { \partial u },\frac { \partial v } { \partial x }, \frac { \partial ^ 2 v } { \partial y \partial x }$ are all given or they can be calculated. However $\frac { \partial ^ 2 z } { \partial y \partial u }$ and $\frac { \partial ^ 2 z } { \partial y \partial v }$ are a little different.

$\frac { \partial ^ 2 z } { \partial y \partial u }=\frac  \partial    { \partial  y }\frac { \partial  z } { \partial  u }=\frac  \partial    { \partial  u }\frac { \partial  z } { \partial  y }  $

$=\frac  \partial    { \partial  u } ( \frac { \partial z } { \partial u } \frac { \partial  u } { \partial y } + \frac { \partial z } { \partial v } \frac { \partial v } { \partial y })$

$=\frac  \partial    { \partial  u } ( 5*3xy^{2})$

The calculation of $\frac { \partial ^ 2 z } { \partial y \partial v }$ is similar. What am I gonna do after that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $\frac { \partial ^ 2 z } { \partial y \partial u }=\frac  \partial    { \partial  y }\frac { \partial  z } { \partial  u }=\frac  \partial    { \partial  u }\frac { \partial  z } { \partial  y }  $

This is invalid.  You can only swap the order of integration when dealing with independent variables (ie: in the same ordinate system).

Rather you need to use the chain rule again.$$\dfrac{\partial ~~}{\partial y}\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}= \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\cdotp\dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u~^2}+\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}\cdotp\dfrac{\partial^2 z}{\partial v~\partial u}$$

Comment: I am used to simple application of the chain rule, that one is a little bit odd to me. Could you please explain more?

Comment: It is just $\dfrac{\partial~~}{\partial y}g(u,v) = \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\cdotp\dfrac{\partial g(u,v) }{\partial u}+\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}\cdotp\dfrac{\partial g(u,v) }{\partial v}$ when $g(u,v)=\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial u}$